Shared Flutter Drawer giving Navigation Error
This one is driving me crazy! I have a shared drawer that extends from StatelessWidget. My screens all load in this drawer from the Scaffold (all Screens start with Scaffolds and the app starts with a MaterialApp). Whenever I try to Navigate in the drawer object, it gives an exception:
FlutterError (Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.)

I've tried many things to fix this, but nothing has worked. Here's the drawer:
import 'package:arcadious/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ArcadiousDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const ArcadiousDrawer({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            child: DrawerHeader(
              decoration:
                  const BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 10, 10, 10)),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  child: Image.asset('assets/arcadious_logo.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.contain),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          
          Builder(builder: (context) =>
          ListTile(
            title: const Text(
              '- HOME',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Outfit',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 22,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              final ScaffoldState scaffoldState =
                  context.findRootAncestorStateOfType<ScaffoldState>()!;
              scaffoldState.closeDrawer();

        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()),
          (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
        );},
          ),),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

I open the drawer in another shared widget that is used on all screens. Here's the shared header widget:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Header extends StatelessWidget {
  const Header({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.grey, style: BorderStyle.solid))
  ),
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(child: Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child:
        SizedBox(
          width: 23,
          height: 23,
          child: GestureDetector(onTap: () {
            final ScaffoldState scaffoldState = context.findRootAncestorStateOfType<ScaffoldState>()!;
          scaffoldState.openDrawer();
          },
          child:Image.asset('assets/hamburger.png',
              fit: BoxFit.contain),),
        ),),),
        Expanded(child:
        SizedBox(
          width: 25,
          height: 25,
          child: Image.asset('assets/arcadious_logo.png',
              fit: BoxFit.contain),
        ),),
        Expanded(child: Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child:
        SizedBox(
          width: 25,
          height: 25,
          child: Image.asset('assets/avatar.png',
              fit: BoxFit.contain),
        ),),),
      ],
    ),);
  }
}

I've tried many things - as far as I'm aware, this drawer is always on a screen that always has a Scaffold and that is always a parent of the root screen which is in a MaterialApp. I've tried just popping, and I've tried encapsulating the link into a Builder.

Hi, as what I understand you have issue when you are going back to the prevues screen, as what i see in your code you are using Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil try to replace it with Navigator.push and also remove   (Route route) => false,

Hi Naser, it doesn't matter what kind of action I perform on the Navigator, it causes the same error.

I can't add a comment sorry but something is coming to my mind :
It looks like you're using the context of your builder for Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil. Can you try to use the one from build function by renaming it differently ?

Hi imGok, removing the builder does not fix anything.
